# PHP: how to retrieve all the metrics and dimensions from the Google Metadata API?

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, google-reporting-api

The [Metadata API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/metadata/v3/) states that it can be used to return the available Google metrics and dimensions. There is a working [javascript](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) example page to demonstrate this.

Now I'm looking for a snippet OR documentation page how to achieve this in PHP. I've searched for both without success.

So my question: how do I use the Google PHP lib to retrieve all available metrics and dimensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly from the documentation on the [metadata API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/metadata/v3/reference/metadata/columns/list) you can do this using an API key there is no need for using oauth2

```
 /**
 * 1. Execute a Metadata Request
 * An application can request columns data by calling the list method on the Analytics service object.
 * The method requires an reportType parameter that specifies the column data to retrieve.
 * For example, the following code requests columns for the ga report type.
 */

try {

  $results = $analytics->metadata_columns->listMetadataColumns('ga');
  // Success

} catch (apiServiceException $e) {
  // Handle API service exceptions.
  $error = $e->getMessage();
}


/**
 * 2. Print out the Columns data
 * The components of the result can be printed out as follows:
 */

function printMetadataReport($results) {
  print '<h1>Metadata Report</h1>';
  printReportInfo($results);
  printAttributes($results);
  printColumns($results);
}


function printReportInfo(&$results) {
  $html = '<h2>Report Info</h2>';
  $html .= <<<HTML
<pre>
Kind                  = {$results->getKind()}
Etag                  = {$results->getEtag()}
Total Results         = {$results->getTotalResults()}
</pre>
HTML;
  print $html;
}


function printAttributes(&$results) {
  $html = '<h2>Attribute Names</h2><ul>';
  $attributes = $results->getAttributeNames();
  foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    $html .= '<li>'. $attribute . '</li>';
  }
  $html .= '</ul>';
  print $html;
}


function printColumns(&$results) {
  $columns = $results->getItems();
  if (count($columns) > 0) {
    $html = '<h2>Columns</h2>';
    foreach ($columns as $column) {
      $html .= '<h3>' . $column->getId() . '</h3>';
      $column_attributes = $column->getAttributes();
      foreach ($column_attributes as $name=>$value) {
        $html .= <<<HTML
<pre>
{$name}: {$value}
</pre>
HTML;
      }
    }
  } else {
    $html = '<p>No Results Found.</p>';
  }
  print $html;
}
```

Comment: Snap I missed that sorry, thank you very mutch. One follow-up question: I'm managing multiple websites so I have multiple UA-ID's. Can I specify the UA-ID in the Google_Client(), class so the results will only be shown for one UA-ID? The code you specified here returns a list with metrics but the custom goals are shown as "ga:goalXXStarts" and "ga:goalXXCompletions". For some accounts we use custom goals and therefore I would like to be able to retrieve a list with all metrics and dimensions with custom metrics for that account (UA-12345678 for example).

Comment: I can't find the proper function to do it in the lib -> https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php

Comment: Metadata api returns default values its going to be up to you to parse them into valid goal metadata.  You can use the Management api to list goals for a user but thats a diffrent question.